# React : AatomWithStorage from Jotai is not updating value after signing in

Tags: reactjs, jotai

first of all, I am newbie in both StackOverFlow and coding ^^.

Here are some global informations :

- BACKEND : Rails 7.0.4 / ruby 3.1.2
- FRONTEND : Node v18.18.2 (React)

Here is my goal which is pretty simple :

- getting user data from an authentication request towards the backend API.
- setting these user data in the local storage (through Jotai atomWithStorage).

The bug is that the data setting by Jotai *setAuthUserData(data)* is not triggering components re-render.

Here is the signIn function :

```
// Function to login to backend
export const signIn = (
  login,
  password,
  setAuthUserData,
  setPreauditAnswers,
  setAuthenticationFailed,
  navigate,
  setIsSigninLoading,
  currentURL,
  setSelectedTool
  // setIsPreauditSelected,
  // setIsSupplierAssesmentSelected,
  // setIsAuditRGPDSelected
) => {
  setIsSigninLoading(true);

  fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "users/sign_in", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      user: {
        email: login,
        password: password,
      },
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // console.log("RESPONSE from SIGN IN :\n", response);

      if (response.headers.get("Authorization")) {
        const expirationDate = new Date();
        expirationDate.setFullYear(expirationDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        response.headers.get("Authorization") &&
          Cookies.set(
            process.env.REACT_APP_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
            response.headers.get("Authorization"),
            {
              expires: expirationDate,
              sameSite: "None",
              secure: true,
            }
          );
      } else {
        setAuthenticationFailed(true);
      }
      setIsSigninLoading(false);
      return response.json();
    })

    .then((data) => {
      // console.log("DATA from SIGN IN :\n", data);

      if (data.message === "You are logged in.") {
        setAuthUserData(data); //Here is the line not working as I expect
        setPreauditAnswers(data.user_preaudit);
        redirectUserOnTheRightTool(
          currentURL,
          setSelectedTool,
          data.is_user_admin
        );
      }
    });

  // .catch(error => console.error("SignIn -> ERROR", error.message))
};
```

Here is the atom declaration :

```
import { atomWithStorage } from "jotai/utils";

export const authenticationAtom = atomWithStorage("authenticationData");
```

I see that the local storage is updated after signing in, because if I refresh the user account page, all informations are displayed as expected.

What I tried is :
I made tests in an other component (the header) :

- create a button that do *setAuthUserData("a value")*
- create a button that do *setAuthUserData(null)*

What I wanted to check through these tests is wether the value of the atom changes or not by clicking on each button from an other component, and it changes as expected.

I also tried to set the value of a different atom in the signIn function (provided) in order to check if the problem is global over all atoms. But I could see that it is not global as values are correctly updated for other atoms.

Hope I have been clear enough :)

Have a good and thanks for reading.

Julien